# Parent view doesn't reflect changes by child controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm a bit new to Angular so I apologize if this is a noob question. Basically I have a controller that's trying to change the value on the parent scope. It succeeds but the parent view is never updated.

My parent view looks like so:

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
  <head>
      ...
  </head>
  <body>
    This is the outer view.<br>
    <br>
    {{ welcome }}
    <div ng-view style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get a child controller to change the value of `welcome` as seen here.

```
app
.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.welcome = "Hello world!"
  $scope.$parent.welcome = "It works!!!!!!!!!";
  console.log("Home controller loaded.");
})
.controller('appController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.welcome = "It doesn't work!"
  console.log("App controller loaded.");
});
```

The code executes but I never see the message "It works!!!!!!!" like I expect. Here's a plunker demonstrating my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dywofrx0u3QOaiKe9MsJ?p=preview

Comment: have you read about broadcast and emit events in angular?

Comment: even I am new to angularjs, read about these events they will help you out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For changes to the parent scope to apply like that, you need to nest your data in an *object*.

For example, if your home controller had this:

```
 $scope.someObject = {};
 $scope.someObject.welcome = "Hello from the appController!"
```

And then your child controller:

```
$scope.$parent.someObject.welcome = "Hello from the homeController!";
```

That will work correctly.

Here's the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/idWEgd8QRwts3zyR6vXJ?p=preview

Very, very related: [Update parent scope variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928341/update-parent-scope-variable)

Comment: I personally prefer using a method, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20350686/4451050