# Injecting Logic via controller to controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 separate controllers (no relation) and one service shared between the two.
In controllerA, I have ng-click attribute on an element that is repeated, it is sending a True/False value to a function within the shared service.

When this function receives a call i want to Increment or decrement an integer in ControllerB based on the bit.

ControllerB's Integer should have no dependency on ControllerA, it receives an Count from its own API currently this value is set to the ng-model attribute.

The controllers already share the service.
I am unsure how to "Inject" to Controller B, and alter the value of ng-model.

Also is the architecture incorrect ? Since at some point controllers interact should i force a parent child relationship? It is only going to be for a handful of scenarios this will need to happen.

Comment: Maybe a $broadcast / $emit style of communication between the controllers may suit you. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32209223/440898

Comment: Yet is the ctrlr relationship necessary ?

Comment: Oh wow they are just getters and setters like in .Net ! How cool is that, lol. When you declare the "Service" in the controler is that an instantiation of the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32209223/440898

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

angular.module("MyApp")
.service('authenticationSrv', function () {
    var user = {name: 'anonymous'};
    return {
        getUser: function () {
            return user;
        },
        setUserName: function (value) {
            user.name = value;
        }
    };
});

angular.module("MyApp")
.controller("parentCtrl", function ($scope, authenticationSrv) {
    $scope.user = authenticationSrv.getUser();
});

angular.module("MyApp")
.controller("childCtrl", function ($scope, authenticationSrv) {
    authenticationSrv.setUserName('my name');
    $scope.user = authenticationSrv.getUser();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        <p>{{user.name}}</p>
        <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
            <p>{{user.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```