# Angular JS Error with Parent Child controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting a weird error with angular controllers. The error is reproduced on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3L4gg6jv/3/)
**A sample of HTML:**

```
    <div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="GroupViewerController">
          <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr ng-repeat="a in arr" ng-controller="OneGroupViewerController">
              <td >{{a}} <button ng-click="change(a)">change</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="oneGroupItemsController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.selectedObject">
  </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    function GroupViewerController($scope) {
  $scope.selectedObject = "test";
  $scope.arr = ["a","b"]
}

function OneGroupViewerController($scope) {
  $scope.change = function (a){
       $scope.$parent.selectedObject = a;
  }
}

function oneGroupItemsController($scope) {

}
```

**Errors:**

1. Why does "test" not appear in the textbox though the parent controller object has been referenced
2. when the button change is pressed, why does the textbox contains the new value of `selectedObject`

Comment: Can you provide [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: this fiddle best describes the problem

Comment: I have edited the question based on the JSFiddle

Comment: JSFiddle provided has different code than yours.

Comment: Just re-updated it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made minor mistakes and also its not a good idea to use ng-controller with ng-repeat.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="GroupViewerController">
          <table class="table table-striped" >
                <tr ng-repeat="a in arr" ng-controller="OneGroupViewerController">
              <td >{{a}} <button ng-click="change(a)">change</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
  <div ng-controller="oneGroupItemsController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.updateVar.selectedObject">
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
function GroupViewerController($scope) {
  $scope.updateVar = {};
  $scope.updateVar.selectedObject = "test";
  $scope.arr = ["a","b"]
}

function OneGroupViewerController($scope) {
  $scope.change = function (a){
       $scope.$parent.updateVar.selectedObject = a;
  }
}

function oneGroupItemsController($scope) {

}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3L4gg6jv/7/

Comment: I want to bind "OneGroupViewerController" to the row not the entire table

Comment: Here you go Noor, have updated the code. let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks, The answer works, but I do not understand why we have to define selectedObject in updateVar and why can't we do something like $scope.selectedObject = "test"; directly ?

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You have made a small mistake I guess. Use the below code and let me know if it works. working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q9ruruxc/)

```
<div ng-app>
   <div ng-controller="GroupViewerController">
      <table class="table table-striped" >
            <tr ng-repeat="a in $parent.arr" ng-controller="OneGroupViewerController">
              <td>{{a}} <button ng-click="change(a)">change</button></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
      <div ng-controller="oneGroupItemsController">
          <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.selectedObject">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

// JS file

```
function GroupViewerController($scope) {
  $scope.selectedObject = {};    // this you have to change in your code. 
  $scope.selectedObject.test = "test";
  $scope.arr = ["a", "b"]
}

function OneGroupViewerController($scope) {
  $scope.change = function(a) {
    $scope.$parent.selectedObject.test = a;
  }
}

function oneGroupItemsController($scope) {

}
```

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928341/update-parent-scope-variable) to understand the concept.

Comment: I want to bind "OneGroupViewerController" to the row not the entire table

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you.:)