# modify main controller $scope from ng-include controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, prototype, angularjs-ng-include

I have a header view with his controller included in my page with:

```
<div ng-include="'header.html'" ></div>
```

the header includes an action call like save, update... I want when the user clicks in the header action update my main controller.

But I can't access and modify the main contoller $scope from ng-included page

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'first value';

});

app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.header = 'from header';

  $scope.update = function(){
    $scope.$parent.value = 'new value';
  }
});
```

I've created a plunker demo to illustrate the issue

http://plnkr.co/edit/xeMD2NxUdb6g8CEcRnFu?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating a value from a parent scope in a child scope, I normally use one of these:

1. Passing an object to the child and updating the propriety inside the object
2. Passing a function to the child scope and calling this function to update the value.

In your example, if you use the option (1), it would be like this:

app.js file

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = {
    data: 'first value'
  };
});

app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.header = 'from header';

  $scope.update = function(){
    $scope.$parent.value.data = 'new value';
  }
});
```

Not using `ng-include`, but you can take a look at [this example passing function to a component to update data](http://plnkr.co/edit/QvQ9yFDaTCGgWW2A5lAA?p=preview)

For further understatement of the scopes in AngularJS, you can read [What are the nuances of scope prototypal/prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)

Comment: No problem. Had a lot of problems with this, go I am happy to help. If you are interested there is this [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1) by John Papa. It is a nice read to write better code in AngularJS and he also explains why to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you could use:

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.value = 'new value';
```

Check the [Modified plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CMS1zqrYQ6gFaJMocJwo?p=preview).

But the real solution would be to use a [designated property for each controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928341/update-parent-scope-variable), or better yet use the [controller as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax) syntax.